# Sorting in GridView + Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

What should I do to perform the sorting in grid view?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement code like the following:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

     if (dataTable != null)
     {
          DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
          dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

          GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
          GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}

private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
     string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

     switch (sortDirection)
     {
          case SortDirection.Ascending:
              newSortDirection = "ASC";
          break;

          case SortDirection.Descending:
              newSortDirection = "DESC";
          break;
     }

     return newSortDirection;
}
```

With this code, your GridView definition should read:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="People Names" SortExpression="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="People Ages" SortExpression="Age" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Try to click again on the same column and see if it sorts in other direction.

Comment: Your problem can be solved through this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already added the event or not in your code behind.

You have `AllowSorting="true"` set for the GridView and therefore you need to
have event handler for its Sorting event.

```
< asp:GridView AllowSorting=true ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" >
    ...
< /asp:GridView >


protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)

{

     //Add your code here for handling

}
```