# How to allow sorting of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and enabled sorting. When running the application I click on the first column to sort. And I get this error: "The GridView 'gvOutlookMeldingen' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled."

This is the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOutlookMeldingen" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Melder" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Melder">
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#1A3491" Width="130px"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# (string)Eval("Melder") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Onderwerp" HeaderText="Onderwerp" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="overflow:auto; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOmschrijving" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Omschrijving")%>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Meldingsdatum" HeaderText="Meldingsdatum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OutlookID" HeaderText="OutlookID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: as stated below i can suggest looking into Linq to SQL.  It seems like this table is populated using sql.  With Linq to SQL it makes this a little easier to sort things

Comment: A better way is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966835/sorting-gridview

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are missing `SortExpression`'s in your `BoundField`'s as mentioned in the other answers.

You are also using a `TemplateField` which, depending on what is generating your data, may require manual sorting beyond use of `SortExpression`.

If this is the case, then to sort manually, one method is to add an `OnSorting` callback to the `GridView`, `SortExpression`'s to your fields and a method to callback in your code-behind.

This would result in markup and code similar to (untested):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOutlookMeldingen" runat="server" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    OnSorting="gvOutlookMeldingen_Sorting"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Melder" HeaderText="Melder" SortExpression="Melder" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Onderwerp" HeaderText="Onderwerp" SortExpression="Onderwerp" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Omschrijving" SortExpression="Omschrijving">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="overflow:auto; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOmschrijving" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Omschrijving")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Meldingsdatum" HeaderText="Meldingsdatum" SortExpression="Meldingsdatum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OutlookID" HeaderText="OutlookID" SortExpression="OutlookID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

...and:

```
protected void gvOutlookMeldingen_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.SortExpression)
    {
        case "Melder":
        if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            gvOutlookMeldingen.DataSource = // Asc query for Melder field;
            gvOutlookMeldingen.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            gvOutlookMeldingen.DataSource = // Desc query for Melder field ;
            gvOutlookMeldingen.DataBind();
        }
        break;
        // case statements for your other fields.
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the datasource I use a datatable. so I have to sort that datatable too? do you know how?

Comment: There's a few ways to do it, I usually use Linq out of habit. There's a good SO answer for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable

Comment: What if I am using files from a folder for DataSource, how would I be able to achieve that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491778/how-to-allow-sorting-in-gridview

Answer (score 9):

This code might help (for you guys googling this old post):

```
protected void gvOutlookMeldingen_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["mySessionStoredTable"];
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression // column name
        + " " + SortDir(e.SortExpression); // sort direction
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
}

private string SortDir(string sColumn)
{
    string sDir = "asc"; // ascending by default
    string sPreviousColumnSorted = ViewState["SortColumn"] != null 
        ? ViewState["SortColumn"].ToString() 
        : "";

    if (sPreviousColumnSorted == sColumn) // same column clicked? revert sort direction
        sDir = ViewState["SortDir"].ToString() == "asc" 
            ? "desc"
            : "asc";
    else
        ViewState["SortColumn"] = sColumn; // store current column clicked

    ViewState["SortDir"] = sDir; // store current direction

    return sDir;
}
```

Comment: @ChristopherBruce that's webforms for ya

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `SortExpression` attribute of the columns you want to sort on. And you need to add an event handler to the `Sorting` event to make the sort work on your DataSource.

For more information, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875.aspx), or [this example with sorting and paging](http://forums.asp.net/p/956540/1177923.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I assume the datasource of your grid view is a DataTable so I think you have to add

```
SortExpression="column name"
```

in every  asp:Boundfield that you like to be able to sort,

for example

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Melder" SortExpression="Melder" HeaderText="Melder" />
```

Comment: I have updated the question, I did what you said but I still get the error. --> "The GridView 'gvOutlookMeldingen' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled."

Comment: What is the datasource of the gridview is it a generic list<>, a datatable?

Comment: it's a datatable and i have another gridview which I fill with the help of SQL