# Sort data in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

How to add sorting feature for a grid in C#. Sorting by clicking the the column name of the grid.

Simple sorting like table sorting. How to make this functions?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please show your effort first.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352300/how-to-allow-sorting-of-a-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sorting.........

```
protected void RadgvData_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
        e.Canceled = true;
        GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
        expression.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
        if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != e.SortExpression)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
        }
        else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
        }

        tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
        RadgvData.Rebind();

    }
```