# String was not recognized as a valid boolean on sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I'm trying to add sorting functionality to an old asp:Gridview and for some reason it is being a real pain to work with. I have tried multiple different things and failed. I would really appreciate some help with this. I have looked at examples at The Code Project and MSDN, but nothing is helping me. Here is my latest code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="grdVwCustomer_DataSource" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectingString %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Gridview ID="grdVwCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnSorting="grdVwCustomer_Sorting"
  DataSourceID="grdVwCustomer_DataSource">
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="UserName">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "UserName" )%>&nbsp;
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TempateField>
</asp:Gridview>

protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM vPanel_Customer WHERE DeletionStateCode=0";
        grdVwCustomer_DataSource.SelectCommand = query;
        grdVwCustomer.DataBind();
    }


protected void grdVwCustomer_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind(Convert.ToBoolean(e.SortExpression)); ****this line gets the error****
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
 protected void grdVwCustomer_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "UserName":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM vPanel_Customer WHERE DeletionStateCode=0 ORDER BY UserName";
                    DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grdVwCustomer.DataSource = ds;
                        grdVwCustomer.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //show message to user
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }



DataSet GetData(String queryString)
    {

        // Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectingString"].ConnectionString;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            // Connect to the database and run the query.
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

            // Fill the DataSet.
            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Log.LogException(Forbin.Logging.PageType.CustomerManage,   Logging.MessageType.Exception, ex.ToString());
            UIUtils.ShowMessageToUser("OnErrorMesg", this.Page);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

The error `Guid should be 32 digits...` shows on this line CustomerID = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

Comment: so...where's the problem, which line?

Comment: edited original post to show which line gets the error, thanks for pointing that out @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the **SortExpression** your sort expression is `SortExpression="UserName"`, yet you are trying to convert it to a boolean here `Convert.ToBoolean(e.SortExpression)`

UserName is not a boolean value, and of course will fail, for safe conversions (though not specifically to get it working for your scenario, you can do `bool.TryParse("true", out myBoolVar)`

Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352512/167304) to get an idea on how to properly use SortExpression and allow sorting.

Comment: Thanks, I added `case "UserName": if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending){grdVwCustomer.DataSource = "SELECT * FROM vPanel_Customer WHERE DeletionStateCode=0 ORDER BY UserName"; grdVwCustomer.DataBind();}` to the code behind and now have the error `DataSource does not allow server-side paging` on the `DataBind()` line. Do I need something else in the case statement?

Comment: @jlg you're trying to run serverside code, which it won't like.  Try running the query separately and then binding the result set, like in this example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, run the query get `DataSet` (though I believe you can do with a `DataTable` and even with a collection of `POCO`'s) then bind that to your grid.

Comment: I tried to use the example that you provided @Jason. I get the error `Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes ....` I'll add my edit to the original post.

Comment: @jlg it's obvious `e.CommandArgument.ToString()` is not a valid guid, as the error suggests, you need to debug and see what you are getting and why, I don't think it is at all related to how to use SortExpression

Comment: Oh. Ok. I will check it out. That part of the code has been working since it was built in 2008 so I wonder what happened. I assume it's bad data. Thanks