# Selecting Edit on row returns wrong row after sorting

Tags: asp.net

I am currently setting my GridView AllowSorting = true.  The sorting works fine, but when I click on the edit button for a specific row after sorting, the wrong row gets returned.  It edits the row that was previously in the position of the current row before sorting.

Here is my code in the Sorting event.

```
string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
            string direction = string.Empty;
            if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                direction = " DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                direction = " ASC";
            }

            DataTable table = Session["WebUserDT"] as DataTable;

            table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
            grdWebUser.DataSource = table;
            grdWebUser.DataBind();
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: set the edititemindex = -1 and selectedindex = -1 right before the direction = "desc" and direction ="asc"

Comment: Hi, this did not seem to solve the problem.  Still reacting the exact same way.

Comment: Take a look at this question, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending

Answer (score 0):

You should get dataTabe in an WiewState and in rowEditing function you should set this as gridview datasource and bind the gridview and it will be solved