# How can I ascending by Date in a grid?

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, webforms

[image]I'm making a search list through a grid in asp.net web form.
I am using web service for loading the grid. Now how can I ascending the Request Date ??

```
 gvproposal.DataSource = webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
 gvproposal.DataBind();
```

here I simply bind the web service now how can I ascending the date??

```
public IS_LC_REQUEST[] EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
```

this is web service method.

```
 public class IS_LC_REQUEST : CModelBaseOfIS_LC_REQUEST
    {
        public IS_LC_REQUEST();
        public string BENEFICIARY_ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string BENEFICIARY_NAME { get; set; }
        public string BRANCH_ID { get; set; }
        public string PORT_OF_SHIPMENT { get; set; }
        public string REQUEST_DATE { get; set; }
        public string REQUEST_ID { get; set; }

    }
```

Updated:

```
var arrayOfObjects = IntBankProposal.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
var dt = DateTime.Now;
gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(load => { if (DateTime.TryParse(load.REQUEST_DATE, out dt)) { return dt; } else { return DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100); } }).ToArray();
gvproposal.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can't you do this in Sql ?

Comment: Also show code of `EnquiryGetAllLcRequest()` ?

Comment: no ..im using oracle.

Comment: I mean you can do this in query from where you load records.

Comment: Is webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest() returns datatable ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table

Comment: Post your full code-behind and I can take a look tomorrow morning. There is some issues with your code-behind.

Comment: Also, try the third code snippet that I just posted.

Comment: Did you get this sorted in correct order?

Comment: If not then try the second and third code snippets again since I have made a minor change in them. Both work without issues on my side. You can see a screen shot of how it ordered on my side: http://screencast.com/t/NJkOpucspZ

Comment: seriously.I can't find any problem.why my output look so strange.still the order looks 15,17,29,13,29,27,15.

Comment: I am working in asp.net web form.Is it any problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to sort the collection you receive from web service call.
Since `REQUEST_DATE` is of string type, you need to convert it to date using `Date.Parse`. Make sure that you include this namespace in your code `using System.Linq;`

*The code below assumes that REQUEST_DATE string contains valid date values*

```
var arrayOfObjects =  webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e.REQUEST_DATE)).ToArray();
gvproposal.DataBind();
```

*If you expect invalid date values in REQUEST_DATE, then use the code snippet below*

```
var arrayOfObjects =  webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime dtNull = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100);
gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(e => { dt = DateTime.MinValue; if(DateTime.TryParse(e.REQUEST_DATE, out dt)) { return dt;} else { return dtNull;}}).ToArray();
gvproposal.DataBind();
```

Another code snippet when invalid date strings could be there is as below.**Try this also.**

```
var arrayOfObjects =  webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
 gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(e => { dt = DateTime.MinValue; DateTime.TryParse(e.REQUEST_DATE, out dt); return dt;}).ToArray();
gvproposal.DataBind();
```

I tried the above code on my machine using an object like the one you have and it worked perfectly as you can see in screen shot belwo.

[image: Sort on Object's Date Property for Array of Objects using LINQ]

Comment: Thank you.Your answer work for me.I just need some edit to work. If i remove e to something else and remove the Date.Parse. It works smoothly.

Comment: can you please help me to ascending the date. `REQUEST_DATE` is string. So i want to ascending as date.And if i write  `Date.Parse(e.REQUEST_DATE)` then it gives `The name 'Date' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: Can you convert the string type to DateTime in the web service which returns the collection? So the class `IS_LC_REQUEST` is defined so `REQUEST_DATE` is of DateTime type.

Comment: No..i can't convert it.If I write `gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(load => Convert.ToDateTime(load.REQUEST_DATE)).ToArray();` It says string is not valid

Comment: That should work using Convert. What error do you see? Just use DateTime instead. I will correct it.

Comment: Use the latest code I have in which I use DateTime.Parse vs Date.Parse. It should work.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I think you have invalid datetime values in REQUEST_DATE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100547/discussion-between-s-rusdana-and-sunil).

Comment: Let me provide a code snippet to deal with invalid values. Then let's go there. Give me a minute.

Comment: How can I convert to valid string date?

Comment: Look at second code snippet I have added which will take care of invalid date values and put them at the top of sort order like a query puts null values at the top.

Comment: I have tried the second code snippet in LINQPad and it works with invalid date values.

Comment: `var arrayOfObjects =  webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest();
gvproposal.DataSource = arrayOfObjects.OrderBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e.REQUEST_DATE)).ToArray();
gvproposal.DataBind();`this one??Sorry this one not working.

Comment: No. I have another code snippet that I just added. Please use the second code snippet in my answer. You are still using the first code snippet which will only work when the date values are valid in REQUEST_DATE.

Comment: I add a photo in the question.You can see that the order comes like that after the second code.

Comment: That is ascending order i.e. earlier date comes before later date. So it's correct.

Comment: You can optimize it further by moving `var dt = DateTime.Now;` to just before the second line.

Comment: 12/13/2015,12/15/2015,12/17/2015.I thing It should the order.

Comment: yes that order is ascending order. Its Dec 13th 2015, Dec 15th 2015, Dec 17th 2015 etc.

Comment: That should not happen. I don't know what code you are running. I am 100% sure you are not running this code correctly. Can you paste all your code so I can see where you are making a mistake? May be you are calling the same code twice one after the other.

Comment: Ok. Can you  paste the actual value of REQUEST_DATE for the fifth, sixth and seventh records in the image you added? I am curious to know what those strings are.

Comment: Also, in which event do you call this data binding code in your code-behind?

Comment: You can come to discussion else this will take too long. I suspect there is some other code that could be causing this.

Comment: I am sorry I have to leave if you are busy now, but that second code snippet works as I tested it in LINQPAD on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OrderBy` method of `linq`

```
gvproposal.DataSource = webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest().ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.REQUEST_DATE);
gvproposal.DataBind();
```

Comment: 'INewwsEnquery.IS_LC_REQUEST[]' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'INewwsEnquery.IS_LC_REQUEST[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). It shows error :(

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @S.Rusdana Try `webservice.EnquiryGetAllLcRequest().AsEnumerable().ToList()` before assigning `ToList()` property.

Answer (score 1):

Set `AllowSorting` property to true, add `OnSorting` event to the gridview. Then  add conditions for sorting in `OnSorting` event. You can try this [reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663532/How-to-Perform-Sorting-in-Gridview-in-ASP-NET) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort ascending order on date filed. Do, as following.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdHeader" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="false" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="780" runat="server"  OnSorting="grdHeader_OnSorting" EnableViewState="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="REQUEST_DATE" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="REQUEST_DATE" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

By default gridview is ascending order. For more information, please visit.
[GridView sorting: SortDirection always Ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending)