# "The ORDER BY sort key(s) type must be order-comparable" with dynamic data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sorting, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm trying to create a Dynamic Data website which should allow an administrator to directly edit the data in most tables in a database.

So far, I have an EDMX and POCO classes, all attached to an Interface used to apply the DataAnnotations on the fields.
I want to have an editable grid for each table, so I edited the ListDetails template and followed [these instructions](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/10/dynamic-data-custom-pages.html), which allows me to have inline editing in a ListView.
With all of these, I can display and edit data. It works.

But when I click on the header (it is a `LinkButton` with the `Sort` Command and the column name as CommandArgument) of a ForeignKey column, I always get the following exception (but the sorting works on "simple" properties) :

> [EntitySqlException: The ORDER BY sort key(s) type must be
>   order-comparable. Near member access expression, line 6, column 3.]
>   Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1325
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +167
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +22    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +974

Example of the table I'm trying to display and sort (I'm displaying and editing LINK_ENTITES_MODELISEES, I'm trying to sort on the LOV_LOB column)  :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ILINK_ENTITES_MODELISEES_MetaData))]
public partial class LINK_ENTITES_MODELISEES : ILINK_ENTITES_MODELISEES_MetaData
{
    public int id_entite_modelisee { get; set; }
    public short id_entite { get; set; }
    public short id_lob { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_val_debut { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_val_fin { get; set; }

    public virtual LOV_ENTITE LOV_ENTITE { get; set; }
    public virtual LOV_LOB LOV_LOB { get; set; }
}

public partial interface ILINK_ENTITES_MODELISEES_MetaData
{
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id_entite_modelisee is required")]
    int id_entite_modelisee { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id_entite is required")]
    short id_entite { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id_lob is required")]
    short id_lob { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "date_val_debut is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    System.DateTime date_val_debut { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "date_val_fin is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    System.DateTime date_val_fin { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "entite")]
    LOV_ENTITE LOV_ENTITE { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "lob")]
    LOV_LOB LOV_LOB { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ILOV_LOB_MetaData))]
[DisplayColumn("libelle", "libelle", false)]
public partial class LOV_LOB : ILOV_LOB_MetaData
{
    public short id { get; set; }
    public string libelle { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_val_debut { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date_val_fin { get; set; }
}

public partial interface ILOV_LOB_MetaData
{
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id is required")]
    short id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "libelle is required")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    string libelle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "date_val_debut is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    System.DateTime date_val_debut { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "date_val_fin is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    System.DateTime date_val_fin { get; set; }
}
```

It probably doesn't work because it's trying to sort on the object property and not the label it's using, but I would expect Dynamic Data to handle that (it uses the first string property as the display value, why can't it use it for sorting ? Moreover I also tried to add the DisplayColumn attribute, with the same result).

I tried to handle the event `ListView.OnSorting` to manually edit the EntityDataSource.OrderBy property, adding the value `it.LOV_LOB.libelle` manually, for testing. It didn't work.
I also tried to handle EntityDataSource.OnSelecting to see what is the value of EntityDataSource.OrderBy (if I don't set it manually it is always `null` even when the sorting works). It looks like it is ignored or replaced after this event. And the Exception doesn't specify what OrderBy it's trying to apply, so I'm not sure what it's trying to do.
I tried to implement `IComparable` but it didn't work. 
I overrided the ToString() to provide the display value, it didn't work either.

I'm out of idea. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did :

As the `Sort` command wasn't working, I made it work by specifying the sorting parameters myself :

- In the template linked in the OP, I changed the command name in the header `CommandName = "Sort"` to a custom one `CommandName = "CustomSort"`
- Add the mapping to the `ListView` in the aspx page : `OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand"`
- In the page CodeBehind, I handled the custom command (I know, storing the info in the `Session` is a bad idea. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending)) :

  ```
  protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.CommandName == "CustomSort")
      {
          var sortInfos = Session["SortInfos"] as SortInfos;
          var sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
          if (sortInfos != null && sortInfos.Sort == e.CommandArgument.ToString())
          {
              sortDirection = sortInfos.SortDirection.HasValue && sortInfos.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
          }

          //Get columns metadata
          var data = table.Columns.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == e.CommandArgument.ToString());

          string filter = null;
          if (data is MetaForeignKeyColumn)
              filter = String.Format("{0} {1}", data.SortExpression, sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc");
          else
              filter = String.Format("it.{0} {1}", data.SortExpression, sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc");

          GridDataSource.OrderBy = filter;
          GridDataSource.AutoGenerateOrderByClause = false;

          Session["SortInfos"] = new SortInfos() { Sort = e.CommandArgument.ToString(), SortDirection = sortDirection };
      }
  }
  ```

  `GridDataSource` is my `EntityDataSource` object.
  `SortInfos` is just a POCO class with `Sort` and `SortDirection` properties

It worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Sort on `LOV_LOB.id` or one of the other `LOVE_LOB` attributes. As a LOV_LOB object itself has not sortable conventionally, i.e by number or datetime, or alphabetically, but it's attributes are.

Comment: I'm using Dynamic Data here, which means I don't have any query, everything is automatically handled by `EntityDataSource`, `QueryExtender` and `DynamicFilterExpression`. As I mentioned, I tried to manually force the `EntityDataSource.OrderBy` to any property of the object but it seems to be ignored.
I know how to sort a query in SQL or Entity Framework, but I can't find how to do that with Dynamic Data.

Comment: have you tried to implement the IComparable interface?

Comment: Yep. No success. ToString() too.